# How do I filter view two columns OR instead of AND?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

In Google Sheets, I want to filter view my results so only rows with an "x" in column D AND/OR column E are shown.  If I filter to show the columns with an "x" in them, it will only show rows with an "x" in column D AND column E.

How do I make it do AND/OR?  When I click the filter button in the column it just asks me to select which entries I want to show.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Drop the AND entirely. OR will work fine for D, E or D and E both. If column D contains 'X', it matches. If column E contains it, it matches. If both of them contain it, you have a match. (And *Thoughts?* is not a question here. You're liable to collect some downvotes as a result. See [ask].)

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it to do that.  I updated my question and added a screenshot.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

- Click on Column D.
- On the menu click 'Data'.
- Select 'Create a filter'.
- Click the filter icon that appeared at the top of Column D.
- Select 'Filter by condition'.
- Click the 'None' box and scroll down to 'Custom formula is'.
- Select and enter `=OR(D:D="x",E:E="x")` in value or formula.
- Click OK.

Alternatively, you can create a new sheet and in A1 enter `=FILTER(Sheet1!A:E,(Sheet1!D:D="x")+(Sheet1!E:E="x"))`. Adjust the columns as needed.

Comment: Thank you!  That first bit helped.  I couldn't figure out the custom formula bit when I was trying.  :)

Comment: @EdNelson  I have a similar question. I'd like to filter where column D is "x" (string) or column E is true (boolean). The following OR condition in the custom filter on only column D does _not_ work: `OR(D:D="x",E:E=TRUE)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try putting true in quotes (E:E="true")

Comment: @EdNelson - Thanks for this, but you addressed a FILTER, not a FILTER VIEW. The big difference is that a Filter affects all viewers, where a Filter View affects only the person viewing the Sheets document at that time.  I THINK I can put the formula you mention into the "is formula" field of the column's filter view selection, but I need it to be "contains" and not "equal to," and to also address an adjacent column. Any help there?

Comment: @DavidinMississippi try =REGEXMATCH(E:E,"dribbling")

Comment: Thanks so much for this!  I can confirm this works in filter views and even respects the range of the filter view

`=OR(N:N>10%,O:O>10%,P:P>10%)`

Comment: For more advanced scenarios, I found this article useful: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-use-and-or-with-google-sheets-filter-function-advanced-use/

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `QUERY` formula like:

```
=QUERY(A:E; "where D='x' or E='x'"; 0)
```

---

```
=QUERY(A:E; "where D='x' and E='x'"; 0)
```

and to make it case insensitive you can use `lower` like:

```
=QUERY(A:E; "where lower(D)='x' or lower(E)='x'"; 0)
```

---

```
=QUERY(A:E; "where lower(D)='x' and lower(E)='x'"; 0)
```

in case you want to use alternating values for 1 column you can use:

```
=QUERY(A:E; "where D matches 'x|y'"; 0)
```

Comment: Where such a formula should be placed? To Custom formula field in a filter view?

Comment: @CommanderTvis no, these ones are for cell input