# How to filter by multiple columns with OR strings...and nested OR within column?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, formula, spreadsheet

Using the 'Filter by condition' option, how can you create an 'OR' filter across multiple columns that contains multiple 'OR' strings within the column(s)?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207299/how-do-i-filter-view-two-columns-or-instead-of-and) is great for an 'OR' filter for single strings in multiple columns:

`=OR(D:D="x",E:E="x")`

How can this formula be edited for nested OR query within the column?

E.g. make column D filter on multiple options instead of only "x", such as ("x" OR "y" OR "z")?

Answer (score 0):

try regex:

```
=FILTER(A2:A; REGEXMATCH(D2:D&""; "x|y|z"))
```

Answer (score 0):

With FILTER, the "OR" function is written like this:

```
=FILTER(A2:A;(D2:D="x")+(D2:D="y")+(D2:D="z"))
```